# Turn off logging to console

Tags: java

When i try to run this code, i face some issues in Level object.

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld{
     public static void main(String []args){
        Logger.getLogger("HelloWorld").setLevel(Level.OFF);
               System.out.println("Hello World");
     }
}
```

Error:

```
  symbol:   variable Level
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        Logger.getLogger("HelloWorld").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported `java.util.logging` package?

Refer- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html